# Counting Change with decimal point (probably simple solution)

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have the following code (I'm not very computer literate so be gentle) that the user is supposed to be able to enter individual coin amounts and the program will tell the user how much money they have in said coin amounts.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Coins {
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println ("Lab 2 by Maria T Williams\n");

    quarterAmount( );
    dimeAmount( );
    nickelAmount( );
    pennyAmount( );
  }

  public static void quarterAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters: ");
    int quarterNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = quarterNumber * 0.25;
    System.out.print(quarterNumber + " You have $" + amount);
    System.out.println(" worth of quarters.");
  }

  public static void dimeAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes: ");
    int dimeNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = dimeNumber * .10;
    System.out.print(dimeNumber + " You have $" + amount);
    System.out.println(" worth of dimes.");
  }

  public static void nickelAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels: ");
    int nickelNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = nickelNumber * 0.05;
    System.out.print(nickelNumber + " You have $" + amount);
    System.out.println(" worth of nickels.");
  }

  public static void pennyAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies: ");
    int pennyNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = pennyNumber * 0.01;
    System.out.print(pennyNumber + " You have $" + amount);
    System.out.println(" worth of pennies.");
  }
}
```

If I enter an amount that has a number in the 100s place that isn't "0" I'm fine. But if I enter, say, two quarters I get back "$0.5" instead of "$0.50".

Comment: What about keeping the internal sum in cents and just converting the final sum back into #.##?

Comment: Use `System.out.printf(...)` not out.println. Use a formatter for your floating point number, something like %0.2f. Either that or use a NumberFormat getCurrencyInstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to force the number to be formatted as you'd like it. E.g.:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double amount = dimeNumber * .10;
System.out.print(dimeNumber + " You have $" + df.format(amount) + " worth of dimes.");
```

Comment: Anywhere I try to add that code I get this: File: C:\Users\Theria\Downloads\Coins.java  [line: 29]
Error: DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Maria Since `DecimalFormat` isn't in the `java.lang` package, you should either fully qualify it (i.e., use `java.text.DecimalFormat`) or add an import statement (`import java.text.DecimalFormat;`) before your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

When outputting the result of your calculation, you can use a `DecimalFormat` like this:

```
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    System.out.println(f.format(dimeNumber));
```

Comment: File: C:\Users\Theria\Downloads\Coins.java  [line: 29]
Error: DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: My putting the code in the wrong place maybe? Again, very computer illiterate

Comment: try adding an import: import java.text.DecimalFormat;